# Getting the IPAddress from a shared path URL

Tags: c++, macos, network-programming

I get the URL after mounting a folder as : "smb://administrator@mypc/sharedfolder/",with this path i want to extract the IP address.I tried using getaddrinfo but no success.
I am working on OS X 10.9

```
struct hostent  *hInfo;

hInfo = gethostbyname("mypc");
unsigned long outIPAddress = ntohl(*(unsigned long*)hInfo->h_addr_list[0]);
```

The same code works if instead of "mypc" as "www.google.com"

Comment: Which part do you have trouble with, extracting the hostname (`mypc`) or resolving the hostname to an ip-address (using e.g. `gethostbyname`)?

Comment: And your code is...? Do you know that you can´t feed the whole string to getaddrinfo ?

Comment: @deviantfan Yes I know that i cant feed the entire path

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I am having problem in resolving the hostname to an ip-address

Answer (score 0):

You have to resolve the domain to an IP-Address. In this case "mypc".

Extract the domain from the Url Syntax:

> scheme://[user:password@]domain:port/path?query_string#fragment_id

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator#Syntax

edit: quote

Comment: Yes I tried that,after extracting the domain but i could never get the IP address

Comment: Could you post the output of nslookup mypc

Comment: I think the issue might be that samba or whatever smb implementation you're using is not using DNS but WINS. If that's the case you should check if nmblookup is installed on your system. 
https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages/nmblookup.1.html